# What happened to "accented velars" in Anatolian?

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, hittite, anatolian

One of the oldest splits within Indo-European was between the Centum and Satem languages; they differ in what they did to the "accented velar" phonemes (like **ḱ* and **ǵ*).

However, if I understand right, the Anatolian languages split off some time before the Centum-Satem division happened.

So, what happened to "accented velars" in Anatolian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Melchert argues that the "plain velars" and "accented velars" remained distinct in Proto-Anatolian, because they show different reflexes in Luvian: **k* becomes Luvian *k*, while **ḱ* becomes Luvian *z*.

He cites as an example the Luvian pronoun *zi-* "this" from PIE **ḱis*, cognate with Hittite *ki-*, Latin *cis*, OCS *sь*, English *he*, etc.

Comment: The claim originated with Melchert (as far as I know), but I don’t think it’s really a case of just “Melchert argues” anymore – in my experience, most Indo-Europeanists accept the three-way distinction in Luvian nowadays. It seems as close to _communis opinio_ as anything in Anatolian ever seems to get.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's fair! In that case I'll probably move the accepted answer to this one—nothing against Fournet's answer, but if there's a decent scholarly consensus on this, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Before you do accept it please read: Melchert, H. Craig "Luvo-Lycian Dorsal Stops Revisited" (Online: UCLA, 2011); Available from Author through UCLA at https://linguistics.ucla.edu/people/Melchert/melchertopava.pdf (Accessed: 19/3/2021). Melchert has revised his opinions!

Comment: @Ned Very interesting! I need to examine this more closely, but to my understanding he still argues for a three-way distinction in Proto-Anatolian, since the *Ḱ series underwent a conditioned change that the *K series didn't? They merged afterward, but this change can't have happened before Proto-Anatolian or we'd see it in Hittite.

Comment: True, but the more nuanced approach, based on a lot less words, makes this far less compelling evidence for a three-way split, and as the scholarly view moved towards the three-way split following Melchert's initial, now mostly withdrawn, discovery it means (in my view) that the jury has to be out until some more compelling evidence either for the 3-way split or against it comes along.

Comment: @Ned To me it still seems like solid evidence—you can't have palatalization affect Ḱ and not K unless they're distinct at some point later than Proto-Anatolian, after all. Even if they merged in some environments, the fact that they didn't merge in _all_ environments still requires a distinction to be reconstructed.

Answer (score 7):

Several points:
1. some people have put into question the distinction between the k, g, gh series (usually called "velars") and your "accented velars" *ḱ, *ǵ, *ǵh (usually called "palato-velars") in PIE. IMO this is hardly defensible, and the distinction is doubtless necessary.
2. the conventional view is that both velars and palato-velars become k or kk in Hittite. See for example Kloeckhorst's etymological dictionary of Hittite.
3. some people (like Pisani) have challenged that point of view. IMO there's indeed a problem with the conventional approach. And I rather believe that the so-called velars become spirants h and hh in Hittite.

Comment: Fascinating! Do you have any examples of PIE *_k_, *_g_, or *_gh_ becoming Hittite _h_ or _hh_? If so, that would round out this answer nicely (and I'd happily accept it).

Comment: for *k, a good example is "blood" *H1es-rk => Hittite eshar vs Old Indian asrk. I think we don't need to posit that Hittite is from *H1esH2r. If *k > h is accepted, then the equation is perfect. Another item is Hittite *huis- "to live", which can easily be derived from *gweyH- "to be alive". Of course, if we accept the spirantisation of velars in Hittite, it changes the picture of Hittite etymology.

Answer (score 3):

Whether you believe that *k and *ḱ merged to a single phoneme in Anatolian, or that *k split into *k and *ḱ after the separation of Anatolian from IE - in both cases you will get the same result.

Comment: Not quite the same result: the three-way distinction still discernible (just) in Luvian is best explained a merger within Anatolian (see Draconis’ new answer).